# Add EventSetter dynamically on runtime to existing Hierarchical Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, eventsetter

I have a WPF `TreeView` control, which gets hierarchical data by binding. To control the visual output in the control I use `Hierarchical Data Templates`. The `DataContext` of the `TreeView` is an `ObservableCollection` of a custom class which can hold different kind of children types.

```
public class PaletteGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Palette> Palettes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PaletteGroup> PaletteGroups { get; set; }

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new CompositeCollection()
            {
                new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Palettes },
                new CollectionContainer() { Collection = PaletteGroups }
            };
        }
    }
}

public class Palette
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As the `PaletteGroup` class can hold childrens of type `Palette` and `PaletteGroup`, I use a `CompositeCollection` to combine both `ObservableCollection`s in one hierarchy for the visual output in the `TreeView`, because of my classes it is possible to have as many subnode levels you want.

The visual output itself is defined in my xaml file, where I use the `Name` property of the two classes to show the name of the object:

```
<local:DragDropDecorator AllowDrop="True"
                         AllowPaletteItems="False"
                         AllowPaletteGroups="True"
                         AllowPalettes="True">
    <TreeView  Margin="10,10,10,40"
               Name="PaletteStructureView"
               VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
               VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
               MouseRightButtonUp="PalettesListBoxMouseRightButtonUp"
               ItemsSource="{Binding LoadedPaletteGroups}">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PaletteGroup}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGreen"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Palette}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="DarkBlue"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</local:DragDropDecorator>
```

As you can see, I also wrapped the `TreeView` control in a custom class for Drag&Drop operations called `DragDropDecorator`, where I add all the necessary events for the controls on runtime. As I use a lot of different controls, I got tired of always binding the events to the controls in the xaml file. The `Loaded` event of this class looks like this:

```
private void DragableItemsControl_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    if (!(base.DecoratedUIElement is ItemsControl))
        throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("DragDragDecorator cannot have child of type {0}", Child.GetType()));

    ItemsControl itemsControl = (ItemsControl)DecoratedUIElement;
    itemsControl.AllowDrop = AllowDrop;
    itemsControl.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
    itemsControl.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseMove);
    itemsControl.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp);
    itemsControl.PreviewDrop += new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDrop);
    itemsControl.PreviewQueryContinueDrag += new QueryContinueDragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewQueryContinueDrag);
    itemsControl.PreviewDragEnter += new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDragEnter);
    itemsControl.PreviewDragOver += new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDragOver);
    itemsControl.DragLeave += new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_DragLeave);
}
```

This is absolutely working fine for `ListBox` controls, which was also a need for my project. But I have quite a hard time with the `TreeView` control, as the events are only raised for the upper most node in the `TreeView`, even if I try the Drag&Drop operations on some children.

First I tried to add all the events to the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`. This works fine for the first level of subnodes, but ignores deeper node structures and also the upper most nodes.

Then I tried to add all the events to the `Hierarchical Data Template` in the `Loaded` event of the `DragDropDecorator` class:

```
if (itemsControl.GetType() == typeof(TreeView))
{
    foreach (object item in itemsControl.Resources.Keys)
    {
        var hdt = itemsControl.FindResource(item);

        if (hdt != null & hdt.GetType() == typeof(HierarchicalDataTemplate))
        {
            var newHdt = (HierarchicalDataTemplate)hdt;
            var test = new Style();

            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseMove)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewDropEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDrop)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewQueryContinueDragEvent, new QueryContinueDragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewQueryContinueDrag)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewDragEnterEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDragEnter)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewDragOverEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDragOver)));
            test.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DragLeaveEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_DragLeave)));

            newHdt.ItemContainerStyle = test;
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I get an `InvalidOperationException` because of an already sealed template object.

So my questions are:

- How can I add EventSetters to an already existing `Hierarchical Data
  Template` on runtime?
- Is this the right way to do it, or do I have
  other options to make this more elegant?

After hours of trying different methods and searching for a solution on the internet I am stuck now. I would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction or even write me a little code snippet which should help me to get back on track.

I hope the code I posted is sufficient. If not, just leave a comment and I will add additional parts of it.

Thanks in advance and for your time!

Comment: You cannot add `Setters` at runtime once `Style` is applied, that is not allowed. But you can of course add event handlers at runtime using Loaded event of some control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself and I would like to post the code here for future reference. Maybe this is not the best solution, but it works for me. I added the following lines to the `Loaded` event of the `DragDropDecorator` class:

```
if (itemsControl.GetType() == typeof(TreeView))
{
    var originalStyle = itemsControl.Style;
    var newStyle = new Style();
    newStyle.BasedOn = originalStyle;

    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseMove)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewDropEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDrop)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewQueryContinueDragEvent, new QueryContinueDragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewQueryContinueDrag)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewDragEnterEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDragEnter)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewDragOverEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_PreviewDragOver)));
    newStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DragLeaveEvent, new DragEventHandler(ItemsControl_DragLeave)));

    itemsControl.ItemContainerStyle = newStyle;
}
```

I wasn't able to edit the style, as it gets sealed once it is set. So I used the  `BasedOn` property on a new style object, to get the already set style information, add my `EventSetter`s and apply the new style to the `Control`.